# An answer was removed, but my flag was declined nevertheless - why?

Tags: discussion, answers, deleted-posts, flags

This is [the answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/425914/50044):

> Mimpi menjadi kenyataan.? Bukan kah segala sesuatu berawal dari mimpi. Selama mimpi kita Masi di tekuni dengan niat & tekad yang keras, pintu kesuksesan pasti kita raih. Dengan mimpi juga, kita mempunyai alunan hidup yang terarah, mau kemana tujuan melangkah. Sehingga kata mimpi merupakan, salah satu dari tujuan hudup. Nyata & tidaknya dari kita sendiri yang menjalaninya.

After my first delete vote, I pushed it to the [Low Quality Posts review queue](https://english.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/270425) via a NAA flag. And then it had "recommend deletion" from 4 others and 2 "delete" votes. In the end, it shows that it was deleted by myself and two others, and of those, one was a moderator. But nevertheless, my flag was declined.

In my experience, it is not *our* job to translate into English. Since the post did not answer the question in the language and standard expected by ELU, it did not deserve being preserved here as an answer.

I'd like to know why flagging it NAA was wrong.

Comment: Nothing absolutely wrong with your flag. I stopped caring about flagging NARA (not a real answer) and LQA (low quality answer) when I earned enough rep to downvote and cast my vote for deletion. Spam and posts containing  abusive language I always flag though.

Comment: I’ve had flags declined (and yet the flag-suggested-action taken) too recently. Kinda shrugged it off. It only really matters if you get flag banned or close to it. Otherwise no one is looking at your helpful:declined ratio or counts except you. And you already have all the badges. The decline doesn’t cost you anything, and you know you were right.

Comment: @DanBron Right, and nothing on the site costs me anything anyway, as long as we are all here to learn something everyday. :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What flag is appropriate for non-English, one-line answers?](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11095/what-flag-is-appropriate-for-non-english-one-line-answers)

Comment: @Tonepoet I'm not sure I understand how this is a duplicate. This is asking about a specific answer.

Comment: This looks like it might be the all-flags-are-one thing again. If someone flagged the answer for a different, non-applicable, reason and that flag was declined, **all** flags on the answer, regardless of type, are automatically declined along with it. This is absolutely idiotic, but it’s how I believe it’s always worked: if a post has both correct and incorrect flags, mods are forced to either approve the incorrect ones or decline the correct ones.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet that's not actually true, it's just that the mod interface isn't very well designed in this respect and it is very easy for a mod to dismiss them all by mistake. And, once done, there's no way to undo it.

Comment: @terdon I was basing my statement on [this answer](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4449) (by a mod) which says that flags are handled in bulk. That was four years ago, though—was this perhaps changed since then?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet either it's been changed or the mod in question made a (very understandable) error. I'm pretty sure it's been possible to deal with individual flags for as long as I've been a mod (since 2014) but it may have been different before my time. However, I also know that I used to think it wasn't possible to deal with individual flags but that was a misapprehension because of the confusing UI.